# Server client communication with loop

Tags: c++

I would like to send an array of characters from the server to the client using a loop, since the information is in different places of the g_messages list. When I run the program, it crashes. Is there any other way we can send these different chars to the client?

We are sending information using Winsock (from server to client).

Any help is appreciated :)

The server code:

```
char *imp=new char[200];

int count=0;
for (auto it = g_messages.begin(); it != g_messages.end(); ++it) {
    if ((*it)->user_name == username) {
        informacion(imp, cmd, (*it)->id, username, baa);
        iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, imp, iResult, 0 );
        ++count;
        }
}
where
list<Message*> g_messages;
```

Comment: "it crashes" is not helpful. Can you run in debug and find what line crashes?

Comment: Dunno if it helps, but take a look at the source code from W. Richard Stevens book 'Unix Network Programming', if you learn the basics from there, your socket code will be correct, elegant and portable. Steer clear of his system call wrappers though, they do not add that much. I use C++, so I usually throw std::system_error on socket syscall errors. http://www.unpbook.com/src.html That book is the standard reference for socket programming.